# TitleCaps program will not translate first character in a String correctly (why?)

Tags: java, string, non-ascii-characters

See if you guys can solve this.  I wrote a title caps program in Java, that is a program which can take a string of ASCII characters and make all words (substrings made up of only letters A-Z or a-z) into title case.  So the string "#@*hello!_world$*" becomes "#@*Hello!_World$*".  But this program refuses to correctly translate non letters at the first indice of the string despite my best efforts to correct it.

```
public static String LetterCapitalize(String str) {

    String newStr = "";
    System.out.println(newStr);

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

        // if first character is a letter and not uppercase
        if (i == 0 && (!isUpperCase(str.charAt(i)))) {
            Character m = (char) ((int) str.charAt(i) - 32);
            newStr = newStr + m;
        } // if first character is a letter and uppercase
        else if (i == 0 && (isUpperCase(str.charAt(i)))) {
            Character m = str.charAt(i);
            newStr = newStr + m;
        } // if first character is not a letter
        else if (i == 0 && (!isLetter(str.charAt(i)))) {
            Character m = str.charAt(i);
            newStr = newStr + m + m;
        } // if character is first letter in a word
        else if (!isLetter(str.charAt(i - 1)) && isLetter(str.charAt(i)) && !isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))) {
            Character m = (char) ((int) str.charAt(i) - 32);
            newStr = newStr + m;
        } // all other 
        else {
            Character m = str.charAt(i);
            newStr = newStr + m;
        }
    }

    return newStr;

}
public static boolean isUpperCase(char c) {
    boolean isCap;

    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        isCap = true;
    } else {
        isCap = false;
    }

    return isCap;
}
public static boolean isLetter(char c) {
    boolean isLetter;

    if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {
        isLetter = true;
    } else {
        isLetter = false;
    }

    return isLetter;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us some examples of inputs and what you expect to get as output and what you are actually getting (wrong).

Comment: In the above example I enter "#@hello!_world$" expecting the program to return "#@Hello!_World$".  But, in fact the program returns "□@Hello!_World$".   Clearly this is the wrong first character for the output string.

Comment: this line is wrong: if (i == 0 && (!isUpperCase(str.charAt(i)))) { - it assumes it's a lowercase letter. You need to see if it's a lowercase letter. Not all characters that aren't uppercase are letters.

Answer (score 0):

this line is wrong: `if (i == 0 && (!isUpperCase(str.charAt(i)))) {` - it assumes it's a lowercase letter. You need to see if it's a lowercase letter. Not all characters that aren't uppercase are letters. So you should have some thing like

```
if (i==0 && isLetter() && !isUpperCase())
```

The other way to do it is have the check for it being a letter come first.